# Adding custom variables to an object

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an object obj which has some variables in it. What I want to do is to add a new variable which has a name i gave as a parameter.
For example:

```
var obj=
{
  number:8
}

function AddField(field_name,obj)
{
  //some magical code here
}
```

If I call

```
AddField('name',obj);
```

i want to be able to do

```
obj.name='Apple'
```

after calling this function.

Any ideas?

Comment: You want to add a field without value ? Why ?

Comment: You could always just call `obj.name = 'Apple'`, if you'd tried it, you'd know it works

Comment: initialize ''name'' in the constructor of AddField

Answer (score 5):

Use square brackets notation:

```
obj[field_name] = value;
```

**REF:** http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html#vId

Comment: OP doesn't seem to want to add a value, just a field.

Comment: @dystroy Then `value = undefined`.

Comment: Maybe. In fact I don't get what's the real question.

Comment: So simple, yet perfect for my need, thank you. I will accept the answer as soon as i can.

Answer (score 0):

Use the bracket notation:

```
obj[field_name] = void 0;
```

This creates a new property with an undefined value.

Answer (score 0):

If obj is already defined, you can just do `obj.field_name = null` or `obj["field_name"] = null`.
I wouldn't set any value to `undefined` even though the language allows for that, simply for a semantic issue: `undefined` means "this property/variable has not been defined" and `null` means "this property/variable has no value".